# Crystal Reports (VS 2010) report not showing up and not throwing any errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, web-parts, crystal-reports-2010

I'm trying to get a Crystal Report to show up on a web page.  My code looks like this:

```
            ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
            rd.Load(@"C:\projects\reports\testreport.rpt");
            rd.SetDatabaseLogon("sa", "thepassword");
            CRViewer.ReportSource = rd;
```

I've worked through several actual errors already to get to where I am now.  The last error I had  was that the connection couldn't be made, but when I added the SetDabaseLogon call to use SQL Server Auth security instead of integrated that problem was fixed.

Now I am not getting any error at all but the report simply doesn't show up.

I'm at a loss as to what to try now, any ideas would be appreciated!

(I don't know if this is really relevant or not, but this is in a SharePoint web part that I'm creating.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this line:
    CRViewer.Show();

If it isn't that simple, then I'd run the application outside of the webpart wrapping to at least confirm/deny if it being in SharePoint is related.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that later today and see how it goes.  I have been able to add it to just a regular asp.net webpage and have it show without any trouble though.

Comment: @BrandonMoore I was thinking about this a bit longer, and I thought permissions might be coming into play. When you're running under SharePoint you get a unique security context. Often impersonated, or at least it could be a different default than a typical web application. It might help to monitor the temp folder with Process Monitor you could confirm that it is making the temporary files it needs to load the report.

Comment: Ended up running outside of SharePoint permanently.  I realized it wasn't really worth the effort and I'm just gonna IFrame the webpage into SharePoint.

Comment: SharePoint definitely adds a layer of complication. It also means working from a much smaller set of documentation/examples since most are make in vanilla ASP.NET applications, not web-parts. If you revisit this I recommend finding (or asking for a sample) on the SAP website/forums, etc. Get the sample to work in your environment, then modify it for your needs. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, one thing I didn't fully realize in the beginning is that creating the web part was basically the equivalent of creating a custom control.  I really didn't need that as this is just used from one page, and doing it that way would have just made development slower and increased maintainence efforts.